# NTFS and FAT32 Drive not Writable 

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive

I am using Mac OS X 10.3.3+, and an external USB drive. I have partitioned the drive into the following:

200gb - NTFS
32gb - FAT32
8GB - NTFS
40 - NTFS

This takes up the entire drive. When I connect it to the Mac, only some partitions will load, and none are writable. On certain Mac machines, a partition was not readable, but on another it was. What may be causing this? Do i need to use a Mac filesystem on that drive? I am transferring files from these Mac's to a PC.

Are there limitations to what filesystems OS X can handle? Or is this potentially a hardware error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed limits to what filesystems OS X can handle, as there are with all Operating Systems. Mac OS X only has native read/write access to HFS+ and FAT (although 10.3 still supports HFS, you should be abandoning it because 10.6 dropped write support). OS X does not have write support for NTFS, so you will not be able to write to them. Unfortunately for you, read access to NTFS was only added in 10.3.9, so you wil not be able to see those partitions at all.

FAT32 is another story. This has been natively readable and writable on Macs for a long time, including in 10.3. You should have no problems reading or writing from any FAT32 partition, so it strikes me as odd that you are struggling.

For the purposes of using the disk to transfer files between Macs and Windows machines, you will have to use FAT32 to get native support on both OSes. My suggestion would be to attempt to reformat the drive to use FAT32. There is a caveat here: FAT32 only supports files with sizes less than 4GB. If you are writing large files, FAT32 will not work well for you.

Please note: all of the above relates to native support. There are projects (eg. MacFUSE) that allow the use of other filesystems from a machine running OS X, but I do not advocate them as a solution to this particular problem. They can be...temperamental.

My suggestion for transferring files between Macs and Windows-based machines is to use networking, as OS X uses Samba to implement SMB and so can fileshare to Windows machines. I also advise upgrading to a newer version of OS X, but that's not directly related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

just use a linux partition to write to the partitions/transfer files between mac and windows.. Linux is free, just download a Linux ISO, and follow one of the many guides for installing a seperate partition of linux

Comment: I am on an older Mac, that does not belong to me fully, that is not possible in this case.

Comment: You could try a Linux Distro that is written for Power PC, almost all of them have a Live Disc option:

http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=ppc